# Android SQLite: How to retrieve auto-incremented userId?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve userId if the userName is known. For example in the function below that I created, takes in the userName and splits out the userId; however, it is making the app crash. So I figured there must be something wrong with the following function as I comment this out, app works fine.

```
public int getUserId(String userName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT userId from users WHERE userName=" + userName;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int userId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("userId"));

        return userId;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I am also trying to save the userId into the shared preferences using the following code, and it seems like this is causing problems as well.

```
   private void saveUserId(String key, int value) {
       settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
       editor = settings.edit();
       editor.putInt(key, value);
       editor.commit();
           }
```

Comment: You should post the stacktrace.

Comment: Doesn't it need to end with a ";" ?

Comment: was userId primary key with auto increment ?

Comment: yes userId is primary key with auto increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you inserted the user name directly into the string, where it is read as an SQL expression.

In theory, you could wrap the string into quotes (`'`), but this would still create problems if the string contains quotes or other special characters.
The safest (and easiest) method to use string values in a SQL statement is to use parameters:

```
public int getUserId(String userName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT userId FROM users WHERE userName = ?";
    String[] parameters = new String[] { userName };
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, parameters);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    else
        return -1; // not found
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Even if the Auto Increment values are `integer` type in table it will be returned as `text` when trying to get from table. Hence you will receive error if you use `getInt()`.So
For getting auto increment value use `getString()` instead of `getInt()`

```
String[] args = { "somename"};
Cursor cursor = db.query("TABLE_NAME", null, "userName=?", args, null,null,null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
{
  int userid = Integer.ParseInt(cursor.getString(0));//here is 0 is postion of column **userId** in table TABLE_NAME

 // or use this int userid = Integer.ParseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("userId")));

cursor.movToNext();
}
```

Comment: @CL. Whenever i try getInt() it does not work and if i use getString() it works fine. I had come to this answer after several tests i made.

Comment: hmmmm.i think that could also be possible which could cause an integer to change as String.I will try to look at it using your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public int getUserId(String userName){

int userId;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(tableName, new String[] { userId }, userName+ "=?",
            new String[] { userName }, null, null, null, null);

while(cursor.moveToNext())
{
    userId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("userId"));
}
cursor.close();

return userId;
}
```

Comment: it's saying to change new String[] { userId } to string?

Comment: Why the conversion into a string and back?

Comment: You still didn't explain what the problem was. (Was it using `rawQuery` instead of `query`? Was it not using a `while` loop?)